# chart based on seconds in the day

Tags: excel, graph

I'm trying to build a graph with a horizontal axis that would be seconds in the day (24 hour period = 86400, that seems to be a problem in excel) with about 20 users ... what I want to show is the number of transactions that a user sends per second over the course of the entire day. What I have are two columns, User and the second of the day. The second of the day and user will repeat for each user and transaction. So if user A send txn #1,#2,#3 in second 4527 and user B sends txn #100 in second 4527 then there would be 4 rows showing 4527 in the second column and three of them with A in the user column and one row with B in the user column. I hope that's clearer than mud. Someone somewhere has to have run into this before. :) Thanks for any input.

Comment: What's your specific issue / question?

Comment: Are you sure seconds is the appropriate unit of measurement here? Transactions per minute or hour is more practical.  People don't think of things done on a per second basis so it won't be immediately obvious what the results mean.

Comment: @Olly - how can I create a horizontally "very long" graph? or am I going to be forced to break it into hours?

Comment: @urdearboy - Yes, seconds are important since our SLA with those users are measured in transactions per second.

Comment: Yes, that's a problem in Excel since there are only 16,384 columns in a worksheet.  You are going to have to either switch axes or break it up into 6 blocks of 4 hours each, if you are sure you really want a graph of this.

Comment: You can still report on min/hours. Switching from seconds to some other unit only scales the SLA, it will not change the underlying methodology. I understand that SLA/Metrics are top down and probably out of your control, but maybe you can put together a pitch and be the guy that saved the company from reporting a non-intuitive SLA. 1 case per second = 60 cases per min = 3600 cases per hour. These are all the same thing, just through different lenses. Maybe, the enforcer of SLA is looking through the wrong lens and this is your chance to shine ;)

Comment: I disagree @urdearboy, 1 case / second is NOT the same as 3600 cases/hour .... I agree maximum rate of 1 case / second  means that the most you can send is 3600 / hour. But if the SLA is 3600/hour then I can send two batches of 1800 lasting 5 second each and still be within my 3600/hour range ... but I just tipped over a server because it's not sized for 360 cases/second. That is why SLAs are typically expressed (in high volume environments) in Transactions Per Second. 1/Sec is NOT even close to the same thing as 3600/hour when it comes to bandwidth or resource constraints.

Comment: Interesting. Was just a thought :) Every case is different and this would be the first time i've seen individuals workload be tracked this way. Usually its automated processes in my exp and those are not tied to individuals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem.

Create a table with 86400 rows, and two columns.

Column 1 = Seconds, and is numbers 1 to 86,400
Column 2 = Transactions, and is a count of transactions matching that second number:

```
=COUNTIF(tbTransactions[Second],[@Second])
```

Use this table as the source for a column chart.

There may well be a more efficient way of creating the transactions per second table using Power Query / Power Pivot... But it's trivial to create the chart you describe.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Olly .. this is not exactly what I need, but if I filter by user it will be. I can move each user to a separate sheet (there are only 20 of them) then do this per sheet and it's exactly what I want. I was just trying to do it all on one sheet with one graph with 20 series on it ... your graph is enough to show me that it would just be a convoluted mess to try to read. Thank for helping!!

Comment: I voted for it but with only one rep it doesn't show :)